# How to place controller in subfolders in CakePhp3?

Tags: cakephp-3.0

I would like to place some of my controller classes in a subfolder (src/Controller/Admin/). Does anyone know how this can be made in CakePhp3?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check the routing section in the cookbook http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/routing.html#prefix-routing

Comment: I want to separate my controller and place it in sub directory, Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you’re looking for Routing Prefixes

https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/routing.html#prefix-routing

Answer (score 0):

This is for people that also want to add subfolders inside an already prefix subfolder.

This way you can have this structure:

`src/Controller/Api/V1/BookingsController.php`

BookingsController:

```php
<?php
namespace App\Controller\Api\V1;

use App\Controller\AppController;

/**
 * V1
 */
class BookingsController extends AppController
{
    public function list()
    {
        die('here we are');
    }
}
```

routes.php

```php
Router::prefix('api/v1', function (RouteBuilder $routes) {
  $routes->extensions(['json']);
  $routes->fallbacks(DashedRoute::class);
});
```

Comment: and what will be the restful uri ?